# how to send image or video to whatsapp status in android programmatically?

Tags: android, whatsapp, share-intent

How to send image or video to the WhatsApp Status (or story) in android.

we can send an image to contact by using:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageURI);
sendIntent.putExtra("jid", "91"+mobile + "@s.whatsapp.net");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "whatsapp image caption");
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
sendIntent.setType("image/*");
```

But how to send it to my whatsapp status?

Comment: did you get an answer to do it?, the app of TikTok is able to show an option to share it bt WhatsApp status, IDK how they did that

Answer (score -2):

```
private void shareToWhatsApp() {
    String type = "video/*";

    // Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // Set the MIME type
    share.setType(type);

    // Create the URI from the media
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(DetailActivity.this, getString(R.string.authority), file);
    share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    // Add the URI to the Intent.
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    if (share.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(share);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));

    } else {
        alertForApp(getString(R.string.install_whatsapp), "com.whatsapp");
    }

    // Broadcast the Intent.
}
```

Comment: <string name="authority" translatable="false">//packagename//.fileProvider</string>

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit how the code solve the problem? Also could you please add your code into the answer by editing it, instead of adding comments?